# Convert decimal/hexdecimal number to timestamp in C

Tags: c

I can read values of elapsed seconds since some reference time which appears in the format `1301330553(Decimal)/4D90BA79(hex)`. I would like to convert these seconds in some `date/time` format in `C`.
The elapsed seconds mentioned above are of `u32 data type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a function called ctime which takes a unix long as a parameter that renders the time in ascii.

Comment: The above solution worked for me. I supplied a u32 data type var and it returned me a pointer to the string of date/time format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about 32 bit linux time then you may want to use the [gmtime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gmtime.html) function.

If you want it as a string you can use [asctime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/asctime.html) to convert it to a nice readable format.

If its not linux time then give us more details!!

Comment: It is a RTOS(SMX) and has smx_stime which is of data type u32 and represents seconds elapsed since time structure is set and is set as: smx_stime = mktime(&time);